# Verification for quote

Tags: source-identification

Can someone verify if this narration is true:

> “Attack them [the Romans] so you can get the blond girls, so that Al-
> Jed said, to him [to the prophet] “do not practice sexual temptation
> on us”. The prophet said to the people, who is your leader, children
> of Salama? They said, Al-Jed Ibn Qais. But he is cheap and coward. The
> prophet said, and what is the solution for someone he is it cheap and
> coward? From today, your leader is Bisher Ibn Al-Bar'a Ibn Ma'rror.

[image]

Source is A'hkam Al-Qur’an, by Imam Al-Qur’tubi, print year 1999, Beirut Lebanon, Vol. 8, Chapter 9:49, pages 87, 88.

Comment: Telling the title of the source you toke this from would be helpful. Why do you hide necessary information?

Comment: Mujahid Ibn Jabr is from the Tabi'een and did not meet the prophet, so the report is at least mursal.

Comment: There is a mismatch between the Arabic text and the provided translation, as the second half is likely from a distinct report from Abdur-Rahman bin Zaid bin Aslam, also mursal.

Comment: @Medi1Saif sorry, will add it.